# Where to find information on weight breakdown for helicopters?

Tags: aircraft-design, helicopter, weight

I would be interested in information on the weight breakdown for the different components of a helicopter. How much of the maximum gross weight is related to the airframe, engine, gearboxes, transmissions, rotor systems, avionics, etc.

Could someone point me to a data source where i can find such information?

I already found a very reliable source on technical specification of helicopters in the Type Certificate Data Sheets published on the EASA website here:
[EASA TCDS List](https://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/type-certificates?search=&date_filter%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=&product%5B%5D=14)

Answer (score 1):

Helicopter Performance, Stability and Control by Ray Prouty has a section on weight estimates on page 663. A few of the equations, rest are in the book:

[image]

I'm afraid Mr. Prouty used imperial units.

Comment: FWIW, for military rotorcraft, there are the AFDD Weight Models mentioned in [NASA Design and Analysis of Rotorcraft (NDARC)](https://rotorcraft.arc.nasa.gov/ndarc/media/Files/reportsAndPapers/NDARC-NASA-TP-2009-215402.pdf) (page 159).